# error : Trying to access array offset on value of type null ( php 8 )

Tags: php, laravel

i looked everywhere for this solution but doesn't seem like there's a specific solution for php 8 as i understood this error is only a php error, so i am trying to send an email using a contact form and this is my code :

the controller :

```
public function _msg(Request $request , $id)
{
    $info = entreprise::find($id);
    //dd($info->mail);

    $this->validate($request, [
        'nom'=> 'required',
        'email'=> 'required|email',
        'telephone'=> array(
            'regex:/^(?:(?:(?:\+|00)212[\s]?(?:[\s]?\(0\)[\s]?)?)|0){1}(?:5[\s.-]?[2-3]|6[\s.-]?[13-9]){1}[0-9]{1}(?:[\s.-]?\d{2}){3}$/',
            'digits:10'
        ),
        'message'=> 'required|min:10|max:500'
    ]); 


    $information = [
        'name' => $request->nom,
        'phone' => $request->Tel,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'message' => $request->message
    ];

    //dd($information);

    Mail::to('jon.reed10C@gmail.com')->send(new SendEmail($information));

    $msg = new messages;

    $msg->nom = $request->nom;
    $msg->email = $request->email;
    $msg->Tel = $request->Tel;
    $msg->message = $request->message;
    $msg->id_en = $request->id;

    $msg->save();

    return back()->with('success','Merci de nous contacter !');
}
```

mailable class :

```
class SendEmail extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

public $information;

public function __construct($information)
{
    $this->info = $information;
}


public function build()
{
    return $this->subject('Contact message')->view('email.msgSend');
}
}
```

the message view :

```
<h1>Message</h1>
 >>>>>>>>>> <p>Nom: {{ $information['name']}}</p>
<p>Email: {{ $information['email']}}</p>
<p>Telephone: {{ $information['phone']}}</p>
<p>Message: {{ $information['message']}}</p>
```

the error points at the same place i am pointing at with the arrows in the message view, i tried dumping $information and it returns an array with the correct information and i dumped $information['name'] and it returned the name correctly, and i tried all the solution i found and nothing worked for me !

Comment: What file and line is the error message referring to, exactly? (And where is that line in the code you have shown us.) Quote error messages verbatim, instead of giving us just partial information.

Comment: @CBroe i edited it, and added some arrows beside it i hope that's enough

Comment: Not sure if it's tied to the problem, but you have `public $information;` in your `SendEmail` class, while in the constructor you assign to `$this->info`.

Comment: @El_Vanja what do you suggest, i thought it's fine to use it that way

Comment: You have to change  $this->info to  $this->information

Comment: This will create another public property called `info` on the object, but `information` will remain uninitialized (`null`).

Comment: @Ruub dude how do i accept your comment .. because it worked thank you so much

Comment: @monaimmatlaya You can't accept a comment, but I made a answer and you can accept that one if you would like to

Comment: @Ruub if i may ask you please .. how can i add "reply to" so the receiver can reply to the sender

Comment: @monaimmatlaya In your build function, you now have: ->subject() and ->view(). You can add ->replyTo(), or, ->cc(), or ->bcc()

Comment: @Ruub something like this : ->cc($this->information->email)

Comment: @monaimmatlaya That should work! But remember, if you want to use the replyTo functionality, you should do: ->replyTo($this->information->email)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `$this->info` to `$this->information`

because you are assigning a value to a property that isn't declared yet. Your blade uses the values that are defined as properties. The property you defined remained empty, because you tried to add your value to a non existing property :)

Comment: While this may be the solution to the problem, it would be a godd thing to include an explanation as to why it solves the problem, so that any future readers can learn something from it. I know the explanation is contained in the question comments, but those are often overlooked.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer trying to explain why that's the answer